# How to get component Object throught its name?

Tags: extjs

I am using formPanel like:

```
tbar: [
        {
            iconCls:'icon-previous',
            hidden: true,
            //id:'previous',
            name:'previous',
            handler:'onPClick'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'tbfill'
        },
        {
            iconCls:'icon-next',
            hidden:true,
            //id: 'next',
            name: 'next',
            handler:'onNClick'
        }
    ],
    initComponent: function(){
         Ext.apply(this, {
            layout: 'fit',

       items: [
        {
            xtype:'textareafield',
            name: 'name',
            autoScroll: true

        }]
         });
    this.callParent();
    }
```

On click of next or previous icon, I want to hide previous and next icon which I am handling in controller.
To show Icon, I am using Ext.getCmp(id of icons).show();
It works fine but If two tabs calls the same view It give Duplicate id Error.

I want to show()/hide() on the basis of name field  specified in tbar.
How should I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get object of component by its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255929/how-to-get-object-of-component-by-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `ComponentQuery` to iterate through the element of any `ExtJS` component,if you don't want to hard code the id.For Ex:-

```
var tabBar = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tab');
```

Then you can further iterate through the element of tabBar element to operate on them.

```
tabBar.forEach(function(i){ 
    //Here you can further iterate through another level if any,and operate on the elements
    i.setHidden(true);
});
```

For more information Refer:-[Sencha Docs For Component Query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)