# How to get object of component by its name?

Tags: extjs

I have a view like:

```
tbar: [
        {
            iconCls:'icon-p',
            hidden: true,
            name:'p',
            handler:'onPClick'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'tbfill'
        },
        {
            iconCls:'icon-n',
            hidden:true,
            name: 'n',
            handler:'onNClick'
        }
    ],

    initComponent:  function(){
      Ext.apply(this, {
        layout: 'fit',  
        items: [
          {
            xtype:'textareafield',
            name: 'name_content'  
          }
        ]
      });
      this.callParent();
    }
```

OnPClick I am doing form.up('id').getForm().

How to get Object of icon-p by its name  show that I can hide or show that icon.

Comment: Are you trying to access the icon-p object from within the onPClick handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onPClick handler you get the reference to the component in the first parameter.
Somewhere in your controller you have the handler function

```
onPClick : function(icon-p-object){
  // do some stuff with the icon-p-object
}
```

When you assign an **itemId** to your **icon-n object**, then you can easily get the reference, when 
you do the follwoing in your onPClick handler

```
var parentComponent = icon-p-object.up(); // now we have the reference to the parent container
var icon-n-Component = parentComponent.down('#icon-n'); // and with that we can get the other reference of the child element
```

The full code should be

```
onPClick : function(icon-p-object){
  var parentComponent = icon-p-object.up();
  var icon-n-Component = parentComponent.down('#icon-n');
  // do some stuff with the icon-n object
}
```

Comment: onPClick can I get icon-n object The reason being I want to hide / show next previous icon?

Comment: icon-n-Component is returning null as I am not setting the id for next icon and I don't want to add id to it.Can we get this object by iconCls?

Comment: why you don't want to set the itemId for the icon-n component? The same iconId can be used multiple times in different container to identify a component.

Comment: If the inclosing view is called by multiple view it will give Duplicate Id error.

Comment: After using itemId its working fine as its scope is within the class.   Thanks for the solution

Comment: Glad to hear the code works for you, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to the item and use Ext.getCmp('id') to reference it

```
    {
        iconCls:'icon-p',
        hidden: true,
        name:'p',
        handler:'onPClick',
        id: 'p_id'
    },
```

To show it

```
Ext.getCmp('p_id').show();
```

To hide it

```
Ext.getCmp('p_id').hide();
```

I've heard people say that assigning 'id' to items can be inefficient (not sure why?) but this is a good way to test what you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps you can find a better way, but this should work.

Comment: Looking up by id is just a map operation, so it's cheap. The reason it's suggested not to use ids is that it can become convoluted once your app grows to any reasonable size. What happens when you start creating multiple instances of the panel above?